# Sitecore 8.1 - Experience Editor and Preview not working

Tags: sitecore, editor, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have Sitecore 8.1 as a multi site instance. The Experience Editor doesn't work, because the rendered URL seems to be rendered wrong. This is how Sitecore calls the Experience Editor:

```
https://hostname.com/de-DE/Site Name/Homepage/Startpage?sc_mode=edit&sc_resolvelanguage=1
```

If I remove the "de-DE/Site Name/Homepage/Startpage" part from the URL, it works.

**EDIT:** If I leave that part and add "sitecore/content/" at its beginning, it works too.

**EDIT 2:** Preview now works once I set preview.ResolveSite to true. Page Editor is still not working.

**EDIT 3:** Here's my SiteDefinition:

```
<site name="sitename" patch:after="site[@name='website']"
    virtualFolder="/"
    physicalFolder="/"
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site Name/Homepage"
    startItem="/Startpage"
    hostName="*domain.com"
    database="web"
    language="de-DE"
    domain="extranet"
    allowDebug="true"
    cacheHtml="true"
    htmlCacheSize="10MB"
    enablePreview="true"
    enableWebEdit="true"
    enableDebugger="true"
    disableClientData="false"/>
```

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Where are all the comments? Were they deleted?

Comment: I have removed the answer since I have tested the solution I have provided but it works from my end when using your configuration.

Comment: So you say the problem are my SiteDefinitions? They always worked from Sitecore 7.0 till 8.0.

Comment: I thought your SiteDefinition was not correct but after testing it, it is ok. Normally, when the Sitecore Dashboard will open, Sitecore will render the path on the Experience Editor Button. When you hover on the button you will see if the link is correct or not.

Comment: You are right: When I hover over the Experience Editor button in the Launch Pad, the link is correct. But when I click it, it is rendered wrong as described in the first post.

Comment: Have you override any Sitecore Method or Link processor? When clicking on the Experience Editor, check in the Network Tab of the Inspect Element and see if there any redirection or something that can provide a clue why the link is being changed.

Comment: I found a partly solution. If I remove the "&sc_resolvelanguage=1" part from the Experience Editor Button's Linkfield in the Core DB, the Experience Editor opens. But the error still comes up when changing the language version while in the Experience Editor.

Comment: Does it make a redirection when you click on the button?

Comment: What do you mean by redirection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110270/discussion-between-hishaam-namooya-and-spacejump).

Comment: Can you provide the value of the `PagePreview.SiteName` in the Sitecore.config found in the App_Config folder

Comment: Here: <setting name="PagePreview.SiteName" value="" /> - Reminder: Page Preview and Page Editor are working now, but now it crashes when changing the language within the Page Editor with a similar wrong URL as before.

Answer (score 1):

In your site definition, check if the root path is the Site Name/Homepage/Startpage.

The "domain.com" represent the rootpath "/sitecore/content/site name/homepage". This means that the url should be something like this domain.com/de-DE/startpage?sc_mode=edit

Try change your Site Definition for this site as below:

```
<site name="sitename" patch:before="*[@name='website']"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site Name/Homepage/Startpage"
            startItem="/"
            hostName="*domain.com"
            database="web"
            language="de-DE"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="10MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"
            useDisplayName="true"
            embedLanguage="true"
            embedLanguageInMedia="false"
            routeSiteName="sitename" />
```

The reason why you can access the page when using the sitecore/content is because you are using the sitecore item path.

Comment: The root path looks like this: rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site Name/Homepage". Do I have to change this?

Comment: Dies it work when you access the experience editor when you use the Site Name/homepage?

Comment: As I wrote the page editor works if I remove the "de-DE/Site Name/Homepage/Startpage" part.

Comment: Try to set your start root to the site name/homepage/startpage

Comment: I tried that, but then the website doesn't work at all.

Comment: Are you accessing the item using the preview mode?

Comment: Ok. The "domain.com" represent the rootpath "/sitecore/content/site name/homepage". This means that the url should be something like this domain.com/startpage?sc_mode=edit

Comment: You are right, but my URL looks like this: domain.com/de-DE/Site Name/Homepage/Startpage?sc_mode=edit

Comment: When you click on the experience editor, does it open directly to the domain.com/de-DE/Site Name/Homepage/Startpage?sc_mode=edit? If it opens, to the homepage only, then the link you click to go to the startpage is not being rendered properly

Comment: This URL rendered when I click on Experience Editor is this: https://domain.com/de-DE/Site-Name/Homepage/Startpage?sc_mode=edit ...and remember, this is a multi site instance.

Comment: Can you please provide your site definition because if i am not mistaken, it need to take the rootpath value from the site definition config

Comment: Added the SiteDefinition to the first post.

Comment: Please see the updated answer with the site definition